# Creating a unique array from an array of objects

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, object, arraylist

My object `demoList`:

```
demoList = [
    {
      id: 1,
      validFrom: "2019-06-01T00:00:00",
      validTo: "2020-06-17T00:00:00",
      xxxM: 50,
      xxxN: 2.2,
      xxxQ45: 2,
      xxxQ100: 1.65,
      xxxQ125: null,
      xxxQ150: null,
      xxxQ250: null,
      xxxQ300: null,
      xxxQ500: null
    },
     {
      id: 2,
      validFrom: "2019-06-01T00:00:00",
      validTo: "2020-06-17T00:00:00",
      xxxM: 51,
      xxxN: 22,
      xxxQ45: 1.4,
      xxxQ100: 1.65,
      xxxQ125: null,
      xxxQ150: 1.7,
      xxxQ250: null,
      xxxQ300: 0.15,
      xxxQ500: null,
      xxxQ700: 15.4
    },
   . . .
];
```

The array I want to obtain:

```
["M", "N", "45", "100", "150", "300", "700"]
```

I want an array of non-empty values starting with xxx and found in the demoList list.
How do I do this using angular?

Answer (score 1):

You can [`.flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) your `demoList` objects to the [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) of each object. You can keep only those entries which start with `"xxx"` and the value doesn't equal `null` by using [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). You can then map each key to either the last suffix number on the key or the last character of the key using `.match(/\d+|\w$/g)`. You can then put this mapped array into a [`new Set()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to remove any duplicates. Then you can spread `...` this set into an array to convert the set back into an array:

```js
const demoList = [{ id: 1, validFrom: "2019-06-01T00:00:00", validTo: "2020-06-17T00:00:00", xxxM: 50, xxxN: 2.2, xxxQ45: 2, xxxQ100: 1.65, xxxQ125: null, xxxQ150: null, xxxQ250: null, xxxQ300: null, xxxQ500: null }, { id: 2, validFrom: "2019-06-01T00:00:00", validTo: "2020-06-17T00:00:00", xxxM: 51, xxxN: 22, xxxQ45: 1.4, xxxQ100: 1.65, xxxQ125: null, xxxQ150: 1.7, xxxQ250: null, xxxQ300: 0.15, xxxQ500: null, xxxQ700: 15.4 } ];

const res = [...new Set(
  demoList.flatMap(Object.entries)
          .filter(([k, v]) => k.startsWith("xxx") && v !== null)
          .map(([k]) => k.match(/\d+|\w$/g).pop())
)];

console.log(res);
```

Comment: trying with stackblitz "ERROR
Error: (intermediate value).slice is not a function" error

Comment: @devedev I am not using `.slice()` in my code, sounds like an unrelated issue

Comment: How can I optimize this code
`
let barems: String[] = [];
this.demoList.forEach(list=> {

  let keys: string[] = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(list);

  keys.forEach(key => {
    if(key.includes("xxx") && list[key] != null){

      if(barems.indexOf(key) == -1){
        barems.push(key);
        console.log(key);
      }

    }
  })
})
`